# Get the domain and page name from a String URL

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

Well i'm currently have some issue about manipulating an URL.

Technically what i want is to get the domain name and the page name from a page.

For example :

```
www.myWebSite.com => domain : myWebSite
http://myWebSite.com => domain : myWebSite
myWebSite.com/xxx.hmtl => domain : myWebSite page : xxx
```

Answer (score 18):

```
window.location.hostname; //Domain name

$("title").text(); //Page name
```

**EDIT:**

```
var loc = window.location;

var filename = loc.pathname.split("/");
filename = filename[pathname.length-1];

alert("Domain: "+loc.hostname);
alert("Filename: "+filename);
```

Answer (score 15):

try with  `url.match(/:\/\/(.[^/]+)/)[1]`

example :

```
var r = /:\/\/(.[^/]+)/;
"http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5343288/get-the-domain-and-page-name-from-a-string-url".match(r)[1] 
=> stackoverflow.com
```

Comment: .march should be .match

Answer (score 5):

Use `window.location.hostname` or `window.location.host`. Check [location reference](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/obj_location.asp).

Answer (score 1):

I hope this helps:

```
function breakDownURL(url) {
    var domain = "",
        page = "";
    //remove "http://"
    if (url.indexOf("http://") == 0) {
        url = url.substr(7);
    }
    //remove "www."
    if (url.indexOf("www.") == 0) {
        url = url.substr(4);
    }
    domain = url.split('/')[0].split('.')[0]
    if (url.split('/').length > 1) {
        page = url.split('/')[1].split('.')[0];
    }
    document.write("domain : " + domain + 
      (page == "" ? "" : " page : " + page) + page + "<br/>");
}

breakDownURL("www.myWebSite.com"); // domain : myWebSite
breakDownURL("http://myWebSite.com"); // domain : myWebSite
breakDownURL("myWebSite.com/xxx.html"); // domain : myWebSite page : xxx
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var url = window.location.href;  //www.myWebSite.com/myWebSite
var arr = url.split("/");
var page = arr[arr.length-1];
var domain = window.location.host;
alert(domain);                  //www.myWebSite.com
var n = page.includes("?");     // if www.myWebSite.com/myWebSite?parameter
if(n)
{
var page_arr = page.split("?");
var page = page_arr[0];        //myWebSite
}
alert(page);                   //myWebSite
```

Answer (score 0):

You can write something like my function below.

```
function getHostnameFromURI(url) {
    // Check slashes in URL
    if (url.indexOf('?') == -1 && !url.endsWith('/') || url.indexOf('#') == -1 && !url.endsWith('/')) {
        url += '/';
    }
    
    let start = url.indexOf('://')+3;
    let end = url.indexOf('/', start);

    let domain = url.slice(start, end);
    
    // Remove port specification from the URL
    if (domain.indexOf(':') != -1) {
        domain = domain.slice(0, domain.indexOf(':'));
    }

    return domain;
}
```

It correctly works with localhost, .co.uk, etc. domains.

https://stackoverflow.com/opensearch.xml --> stackoverflow.com

https://github.com/arichr                --> github.com

**Information:** Please, check that your URLs are not wrong e.g. `https://example.com?a=a` will return `example.com?a=a`