# Getting domain of an URL with Regular Expressions

Tags: ruby, regex, string, parsing, url

I'm trying to get the domain of a given URL. For example `http://www.facebook.com/someuser/` will return `facebook.com`. The given URL can be on these formats:

1. `https://www.facebook.com/someuser` (www. is optional, but should be ignored)
2. `www.facebook.com/someuser` (http:// is not required)
3. `facebook.com/someuser`
4. `http://someuser.tumblr.com` -> this has to return `tumblr.com` only

I wrote this regex:

`/(?: \.|\/{2})(?: www\.)?([^\/]*)/i`

But it does not work as I expect.

I can do this in parts:

1. Remove `http://` and `https://`, if present on string, with `string.delete "/https?:\/\//i"`.
2. Remove `www.` with `string.delete "/www\./i"`.
3. Get the domain with match and `/(\w+\.\w+)+/i`

But this won't work with subdomains.
String for testing:

```
https://www.facebook.com/username
http://last.fm/user/username
www.google.com
facebook.com/username
http://sub.tumblr.com/
sub.tumblr.com
```

I need this to work with the minimum memory and processing coast as possible.

Any ideas?

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/569137/how-to-get-domain-name-from-url a qick googling returns his link http://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/160877

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Why don't you just use the URI class to do this?

```
URI.parse( your_uri ).host
```

And you're done.

Just one thing, if there's no "http://" or "https://" at the beginning of the url, you'll have to add one, or the parse method is not going to give you a host (it's going to be nil).

Comment: Unfortunally, this doesn't ignore subdomains. Anyway, I'll be using this solution.

Comment: To ignore subdomains, try `hostname.split('.').last(2).join('.')`.

Comment: But don't forget you could have arbitrary large subdomains, like "me.you.we.business.com". Subdomains can go 127 levels deep.

Comment: This doesn't get the domain name, this gets the host name. Not sure how this is accepted, it doesn't answer the question.

Comment: This does not work for 'cta-redirect.hubspot.com' :(

Answer (score 2):

This works for me: `/^h?t?t?p?s?:?\/?\/?w?w?w?\.?(.*\.[A-Z]{2,})+[A-Z\/]/i`
It will always give you the domain part only
Take a look at it at:
http://rubular.com/r/0hudnJSgVT

To use it create a method like this, I put it in my helpers so I have access to in in the views.

```
def website_url(website_url)
    if website_url[/^h?t?t?p?s?:?\/?\/?w?w?w?\.?(.*\.[A-Z\/]{2,})$/i]
      website_id = $1
    end

    %Q{http://#{ website_id }}
  end
```

Answer (score 1):

Does it have to be a regex? You could do this also.

```
require 'uri'
yourURL = URI.parse('https://www.facebook.com/username')
print yourURL.host
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use this regex:

```
/(\w+\.\w{2,6})(?:\/|$)/
```

Comment: Not sure why you got downvoted, but your answer is technically wrong as you're not escaping your dots. Even if you did escape them, you wouldn't match facebook.com/username or the last.fm example due to that required first dot.

Comment: @pbaumann, you're right. It was working in my tests but I copied it over wrong. I had to escape the . and remove the first.

Answer (score 0):

If you really wanted to use a regex, you could try something along the lines of:

```
test_string.scan(/\w+\.\w+(?=\/|\s|$)/) { |match| do_stuff_with(match) }
```

This wouldn't account for domain names such as something.co.uk but it would match everything in your test string.

Answer (score 0):

I have created a function for **String** class through **Open Classes** technique for **my purpose**.

```
class String
  def to_dn
    return '' if self.blank?
    return self.split('@').last if self.match('@')
    link = self
    link = "http://#{link}" unless link.match(/^(http:\/\/|https:\/\/)/)
    link = URI.parse(URI.encode(link)).host.present? ? URI.parse(URI.encode(link)).host : link.strip
    domain_name = link.sub(/.*?www./,'')
    domain_name = domain_name.match(/[A-Z]+.[A-Z]{2,4}$/i).to_s if domain_name.split('.').length >= 2 && domain_name.match(/[A-Z]+.[A-Z]{2,4}$/i).present?
  end
end
```

**Example:**

```
 1. "https://www.facebook.com/someuser".to_dn = "facebook.com"
 2. "www.facebook.com/someuser".to_dn = "facebook.com"
 3. "facebook.com/someuser".to_dn = "facebook.com"
 4. "http://someuser.tumblr.com".to_dn = "tumblr.com" 
 5. "dc.ads.linkedin.com".to_dn = "linkedin.com" 
 6. 'your_name@domain.com'.to_dn = "domain.com"
```

It also work for email addresses (which require for my purpose). Hope it will useful of others. Correct me if you find anything incorrect :)

**Note: *It will not works for 'www.domainname.co.in'. I am working on it :)***