# Trying to create pattern for Domain Name

Tags: java, android, regex, pattern-matching

I am trying to create a Pattern to Validate Domain Name without "http://www" ,  but I am unable to do so Completely please someone help me;

```
"\\.[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z]"
".*?([^.]+\\.[^.]+)"
```

Comment: Have a look at this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/569137/how-to-get-domain-name-from-url

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried patterns from class [Patterns](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/Patterns.html) ?

Comment: will you please help me to use this

Comment: in package android.util is Patterns class which contains some patterns: 

TOP_LEVEL_DOMAIN_STR Regular expression to match all IANA top-level domains.
TOP_LEVEL_DOMAIN_STR_FOR_WEB_URL Regular expression to match all IANA top-level domains for WEB_URL.
TOP_LEVEL_DOMAIN Regular expression pattern to match all IANA top-level domains.
WEB_URL Regular expression pattern to match most part of RFC 3987 Internationalized URLs, aka IRIs.

Comment: Yes I read this but not able to use it Please tell me how to use this class

Comment: Hey thanks gabi I was using Android 2.1 so I was not able to implement this. Now i can thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Pattern: `^[a-zA-Z0-9\-\.]+\.(com|org|net|mil|edu|COM|ORG|NET|MIL|EDU)$`

Description
Domain names: This regular expression tests the validity of a domain or hostname. It will match any valid domain name that does not contain characters which are invalid in URLs, and which ends in .com, .org, .net, .mil, or .edu. You can add additional valid TLDs by appending the | (pipe) character and the desired TLD to the list in the parens.

Matches
3SquareBand.com | asp.net | army.mil

For more patterns check [here](http://regexlib.com/Search.aspx?k=URL&AspxAutoDetectCookieSupport=1)

Comment: Note that this pattern constrains on only a few top level domains. It would fail, for example, for domains in .info or .photography

Answer (score 0):

That Pattern API is not perfect in my case so I used this Regular Expression.

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("^(http|ftp|https)://|^[a-zA-Z0-9]+\\.[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z]" );
```

Answer (score 0):

For Java developers, this pattern works for my problem:

```
private static final String DOMAIN_START_END_PATTERN_STRING =
    "^([a-zA-Z0-9]([a-zA-Z0-9\\-]{0,65}[a-zA-Z0-9])?\\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,6}$";
```

Comment: Note that this pattern presumes all TLDs are 2-6 characters in length. This is not the case, with new TLDs like .photography