# get current Domain of UIWebview

Tags: ios, regex, uiwebview, nsstring

I want to get the current domain of UIWebView

For example:

http://a.m.tmall.com/i15104234454.htm?sid=a0c935526ab19ee7051225579c90cf96&spm=875.124399.275145.1 -> tmall.com

Is there any reliable way to do this?

I saw someone suggest this:

```
 NSString *currentURL = myWebView.request.URL.absoluteString;
```

I know regex could do it. Any other way?

Comment: Did the `myWebView.request.URL.absoluteString` work? If it didn't maybe you could try `myWebView.request.URL.baseURL`.

Comment: @qegal no, this memeber seems to be null.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, what do mean when you say you want to get the domain. In essence, how rigorous do you want to be? Domain parsing can be very complex (see: [how to get domain name from URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/569137/how-to-get-domain-name-from-url)).

At the very least start, with URL.absoluteURL.host instead of URL.absoluteString. That way you don't have to extract the host from the URL string.

You may also want use `[webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.domain"]` as your starting point. At least that way you will know what the browser thinks the domain is.

Hope any of that mess helps.

Answer (score 1):

In Swift you get host URL from web view by :

```swift
webView.url?.host
```

more info [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/url/1780168-host)