# Regex to match a capture a domain name

Tags: regex, vb.net, url

Hi i will have URL in following format:

- http://www.youtube.com/v/0PsnoiwMrhA
- https://www.youtube.com/v/0PsnoiwMrhA
- www.youtube.com/v/0PsnoiwMrhA
- http://youtube.com/v/0PsnoiwMrhA
- youtube.com/v/0PsnoiwMrhA

It all must capture and return a domain name as **`youtube`**.

I have tried using

```
(http://|https://)?(www.)(.?*)(.com|.org|.info|.org|.net|.mobi)
```

but it showing error as `regex parsing nested quantifier`.

Please help me out

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to get domain name from URL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/569137/how-to-get-domain-name-from-url)

Comment: @Divi Please consider before reporting as Duplicate. There is a difference and also i've tried those answer. nothing worked

Comment: Sorry but I fail to see the difference. You might want to edit your question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using a field that you know is in one of these formats, you can retrieve the match from Group 1 using this regex:

```
^(?:https?://)?(?:www\.)?([^.]+)
```

In VB.NET:

```
Dim ResultString As String
Try
    ResultString = Regex.Match(SubjectString, "^(?:https?://)?(?:www\.)?([^.]+)", RegexOptions.Multiline).Groups(1).Value
Catch ex As ArgumentException
    'Syntax error in the regular expression
End Try
```

Comment: Thanks for all you answer about regex.

Comment: I'm here right now, will wait a couple minutes then start a movie if I don't see you and return in a couple hours. :)

Comment: Hi are you there. Can you please help me out for this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24778609/parse-url-using-regex

Answer (score 1):

`(.?*)` should be `(.*?)` - that's the source of your error.

Also, remember to escape the dot unless you want it to match *any*  character.

And since the `www.` part is optional, you need to add a `?` quantifier to that group as well.

Answer (score 0):

You could try the below regex to get the domain name `youtube` from the above mentioned URL's,

```
^(?:https?:\/\/)?(?:www\.)?([^.]*)(?=(?:\.com|\.org|\.info|\.net|\.mobi)).*$
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/dP1eW6/1)

It ensures that the domain name must be followed by `.com` or `.info` or `.org` or `.net` or `.mobi`.