# Parse URL using Regex

Tags: regex, vb.net, url, thumbnails

I have Youtube and Dailymotion Video URL as follows:

For Youtube

- http://www.youtube.com/v/0PsnoiwMrhA
- http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ok_VQ8I7g6I
- http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1taai0d1FXw&list=PL1uGXsv9VLdCm_LYVa9c7Rv8DPdflJZfT

For Dailymotion

- http://www.dailymotion.com/video/x21a1i8_brazil-1-7-germany-a-world-cup-2014-brick-by-brick-video-animation_news
- http://www.dailymotion.com/video/x2148xg_brazil-1-7-germany-brazil-player-ratings-from-a-shocking-defeat_sport

I want to get the Preview image of these video, So i have to parse these link as follows:

For Youtube

- http://img.youtube.com/vi/0PsnoiwMrhA/default.jpg
- http://img.youtube.com/vi/ok_VQ8I7g6I/default.jpg
- http://img.youtube.com/vi/1taai0d1FXw/default.jpg

For Dailymotion

- http://www.dailymotion.com/thumbnail/video/x21a1i8_brazil-1-7-germany-a-world-cup-2014-brick-by-brick-video-animation_news
- http://www.dailymotion.com/thumbnail/video/x2148xg_brazil-1-7-germany-brazil-player-ratings-from-a-shocking-defeat_sport

Please help me. I'm newbie in regex...

Comment: Do you have to use regular expressions? Can't you just parse the string and split it on the third '/' You know for the you tube ones you want to replace the six characters following the third '/' with 'vi' and for daily motion videos you want to replace 'video' with 'thumbnail' following the third '/'

Comment: This really contains all the information you'll need
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9099/The-Minute-Regex-Tutorial

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**YouTube:**

```
ResultString = Regex.Replace(SubjectString, "http.*?v[=/]([^\s&#]+)\S+", "http://img.youtube.com/vi/$1/default.jpg", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase)
```

**DailyMotion:**

A simple string replace would do, but here is the regex:

```
ResultString = Regex.Replace(SubjectString, "http://www\.dailymotion\.com/video/", "http://www.dailymotion.com/thumbnail/video/", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase)
```

Comment: For youtube i'm getting like this `http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=http://img.youtube.com/vi/4ioaMXTsAv8/default.jpg` but i want `http://img.youtube.com/vi/4ioaMXTsAv8/default.jpg`

Comment: Gosh, that's embarrassing! Don't know what happened, thought I tested it but I must have been sleep-walking.... Please try the updated code. :)

Comment: Hi, I have posted new question about Javascript http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24836760/uncaught-syntaxerror-unexpected-identifier-in-chrome