# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier IN Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, vb.net, function

I have following script in my page to highlight a map.

```
<script>
    function highlight(list,win,lose)
    {
        var WinParty = win;
        var LoseParty = lose;              

        var jsVariable = list;

        var area = document.getElementsByTagName('area')
        var ary=[]
        for (var zxc0=0;zxc0<area.length;zxc0++){
            ary.push(area);  
           }

        var isfound = false;  

        for(var i = 0; i < area.length; i++)   
        {   
            isfound = false;  

            for(var j = 0; j < jsVariable.length; j++)   
            {                   
                if (area[i].getAttribute('title').trim() == jsVariable[j].trim())
                {  
                    isfound = true;                   
                    $(area[i]).each(function ()//get all areas
                    {
                        $(this).addClass("victory");
                    });
                }            
            }   
            if(!isfound)   
            {   
                $(area[i]).each(function ()//get all areas
                {
                    $(this).addClass("lose");
                });                
            }              
        }                             

        $(function () {
            var data = {};
            $('.map').maphilight();
            data.alwaysOn = true;
            data.fillColor = WinParty;
            $('.victory').data('maphilight', data).trigger('alwaysOn.maphilight');


            var data = {};
            $('.map').maphilight();
            data.alwaysOn = true;
            data.fillColor = LoseParty;
            $('.lose').data('maphilight', data).trigger('alwaysOn.maphilight');
        });
    }
</script>
```

I am calling this script from Code Behind (VB.Net) as follows

```
Dim Serializer = New System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer()
Dim List = Serializer.Serialize(Values)
WinPartyColor = Hex(Color.Blue.ToArgb()).Substring(2)
LosePartyColor = Hex(Color.Red.ToArgb()).Substring(2)

Dim Script As String = String.Format("highlight({0},{1},{2});", List, WinPartyColor, LosePartyColor)

ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(ElectionResultUpdatePanel, ElectionResultUpdatePanel.GetType(), "HighLighting", Script, True)
```

When i'm running above  code in Chrome i'm getting error as

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
```

but when i run same code in IE, getting error as

```
SCRIPT1007: Expected ']'.
```

My guess is about List argument, which is array in Javascript.

Please help me out.

Comment: Which line is the error on? This line: `ary.push(area);` probably isn't doing what you think it is - `area` is already a list, but you're creating an array where each element refers to the whole list. (Note also that you don't need the `WinParty`, `LoseParty` and `jsVariable` variables, you can just use the function arguments directly as needed. Also, "jsVariable" as a variable name? Really?)

Comment: @nnnnnn Yes.. If i do anything wrong make me clear

Comment: @nnnnnn avtually i fonded a error cause, it's cause of `Dim Script As String = String.Format("highlight({0},{1},{2});", List, WinPartyColor, LosePartyColor)`. We have to use like `Dim Script As String = String.Format("highlight('{0}','{1}','{2}');", List, WinPartyColor, LosePartyColor)` but the problem now is `List` is an `array` but it sending as `string`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I fixed the problem,

It is cause of calling script from Code behind:

```
Dim Script As String = String.Format("highlight({0},{1},{2});", List, WinPartyColor, LosePartyColor)
```

I have change is as follows, now it's working fine.

```
Dim Script As String = "highlight(" + List + ",'" + WinPartyColor + "','" + LosePartyColor + "');"
```

Answer (score 0):

That is not a problem with `string.Format` call, you missed to include the single quote in your index `'{1}'`, `'{2}'`.

Please, try this.