# Regex does not work properly

Tags: c#, .net, regex, vb.net, validation

I have a windows form, in which i have a textbox. I want to check using **Regex** that the text inserted does not contain any other character except:

1. Alphabetic letters [a-z] or [A-Z]
2. Numbers, 0-9
3. _ (underscore) or . (Dot)

I have written this line of code which seems to not work properly.
In VB.NET/C#:

```
Regex.IsMatch(txtCreateDomain.ToString(), "^[a-zA-Z0-9_.]*$")
```

I want for example to create a variable like below:
C#

```
bool isValid = Regex.IsMatch(txtCreateDomain.ToString(), "^[a-zA-Z0-9_.]*$")
```

VB

```
Dim isValid As Boolean = Regex.IsMatch(txtCreateDomain.ToString(), "^[a-zA-Z0-9_.]*$")
```

What am i missing?

Comment: [Related.](http://stackoverflow.com/a/967610/6188402)

Comment: If `txtCreateDomain` is a TextBox you should be calling `txtCreateDomain.Text` and not `ToString()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot the underscore and the dash:

```
bool isValid = Regex.IsMatch(txtCreateDomain.Text, "^[a-zA-Z0-9_.-]*$")
```

Comment: This will check only if the text contains all of these right? From my Regex i want all this cases to be valid: domain.intern , domain1.intern, my-domain.intern

Comment: All of these will match, yes. But if you want to validate domain names maybe have a look at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24730805/regex-to-match-a-capture-a-domain-name or https://www.safaribooksonline.com/library/view/regular-expressions-cookbook/9781449327453/ch08s15.html

Comment: Thanx, this solved my issue. :)

Comment: `Regex.IsMatch(txtCreateDomain.ToString(), @"^[\w.-]*$", RegexOptions.ECMAScript)` is simpler, I think. In VB.NET, the `@` should be removed of course. Also, there is no dash in the pattern, only a *hyphen*. BTW, there is no requirement to match a hyphen in the question. That looks suspicious.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Of course `\w` is simpler, I decided to keep it anyway. Thanks for pointing out that it's a hyphen, not a dash, I wasn't aware of that. Regarding matching the hypen: it's not mentioned in the question, but it's mentioned in the comments for my answer and Nasreddine's answer...

Comment: Good, still, the question should contain all the details required to answer it. I do not find fault with your answer, just the question itself.

Comment: I am sorry for the mistakes in the question. I appreciaty your help. Thanx for your time

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
Regex.IsMatch(txtCreateDomain.ToString(), "^[a-zA-Z0-9_.]*$")
```

**Edit:**

Since you're trying to validate domain names a better solution would be to use the solution described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/967610/162671):

```
// https://stackoverflow.com/a/967610/162671
private static bool IsValidDomainName(string name)
{
    return Uri.CheckHostName(name) != UriHostNameType.Unknown;
}
```

Or something like this:

```
var valid = false;
try
{
    var uri = new Uri("http://example.com/");
    valid = false;
}
catch (UriFormatException){
    valid = false;
}
```

Comment: @Nasreddine not if the dot is inside the character class.

Comment: I learned something today. Thanks @user6188402 and lbarros.

Comment: From my Regex i want all this cases to be valid: domain.intern , domain1.intern, my-domain.intern @user6188402

Comment: @drgmak are you trying to validate domain names?

Comment: @Nasreddine yes, I am.

Comment: @drgmak A better solution would be something like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/967610/162671) instead of a regex

Answer (score 0):

```
/^\w+$/

\w is equivalent to [A-Za-z0-9_]
```

Comment: user6188402 - Thnx for inform me. i am new here so didn't  this.

Comment: `\w is equivalent to [A-Za-z0-9_]` - not in .NET by default.