# How to get domain name from URL - Angular 7

Tags: angular, split

How to get ONLY the name of an domain from an url

```
+--------------------------------------------+------------+
| input                                      | output     |
+--------------------------------------------+------------+
| http://google.com/abc.html                 | google     |
| http://www.yahoo.com?abc                   | yahoo      |
| https://youtube.co.in/abc/xyz.html         | youtube    |
| https://www.twitter.au.uk/abc&xyz.php      | twitter    |
+--------------------------------------------+------------+
```

This "output" will be used to create the name of an image "google.png"

On my angular app I have split the code in 3 parts:

**Part 1**

```
export function extractHostname(url: string): string {
    let hostname;

    // remove protocol
    if (url.indexOf('//') > -1) {
        hostname = url.split('/')[2];
    } else {
        hostname = url.split('/')[0];
    }

    // remove port
    hostname = hostname.split(':')[0];

    // remove query
    hostname = hostname.split('?')[0];

    return hostname;
}
```

**Part 2 (here is my problem)**

```
import { extractHostname } from './extractHostname';

export function extractRootDomain(url: string): string {
    let domain = extractHostname(url);
    const splitArr = domain.split('.');
    const arrLen = splitArr.length;

    // get root domain
    if (arrLen > 2) {
        domain = splitArr[arrLen - 2] + '.' + splitArr[arrLen - 1];
        // see if it's using a Country Code Top Level Domain (ccTLD) (i.e. ".me.uk")
        if (splitArr[arrLen - 2].length === 2 && splitArr[arrLen - 1].length === 2) {
            domain = splitArr[arrLen - 3] + '.' + domain;
        }
    }

    return domain;
}
```

**Part 3 - Final step (return +domain+ to create image name)**

```
import {extractRootDomain} from './extractRootDomain';

export function getFaviconFromUrl(url: string) {
    const domain = extractRootDomain(url);
    return 'https://mywebsite.com/img/'+domain+'.png;
}
```

Of corse, this work, but the **return is google.com** - and - **I need just google**

Someone can rewrite the code and paste here?

Comment: check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/569137/how-to-get-domain-name-from-url

Answer (score 0):

Well... the problem was on the first part.
This is the correct code (will split www and . )

```
export function extractHostname(url: string): string {
    let hostname;

    // remove protocol
    if (url.indexOf('//') > -1) {
        hostname = url.split('/')[2];
    } else {
        hostname = url.split('/')[0];
    }

    if (url.indexOf('www.') > -0) {
        hostname = url.split('www.')[1];
    }

    hostname = hostname.split('.')[0];

    // remove port
    hostname = hostname.split(':')[0];

    // remove query
    hostname = hostname.split('?')[0];

    return hostname;
}
```