# How to get only hostname from the url using javascript regex?

Tags: javascript, regex, string, url

I have below urls

```
1) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask?guided=true
2) https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ClkQA2Lb_iE
3) https://trello.com/b
```

I need to get only the host name from the above urls. 
So the output should be

```
1) stackoverflow
2) youtube
3) trello
```

Comment: Please refer below answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/569137/how-to-get-domain-name-from-url

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use pattern `/(\w+)\.\w{2,}(\/|\?|$)/` to getting domain name from url. The regex match any string is before `/` or `?`

```js
var getName = function(url){
  return url.match(/(\w+)\.\w{2,}(\/|\?|$)/)[1];
}

console.log(
  getName("https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask?guided=true"),
  getName("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ClkQA2Lb_iE"),
  getName("https://trello.com")
)
```

Comment: Hi for this one `https://www.google.co.in/` I am getting only `co`... Could you pls check this

Comment: @Profer You'r right. It is because there isn't a right solution to detecting domain name using regex or parsers. Even javascript [URL](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL) object that parse url return `google.co.in` as **hostname** and does not return `google`. I think you have list of domain suffix to do this work.

Comment: So it is not possible? I have to take full url `google.co.in`
?

Comment: @Profer I can't find any solution for it, you can only get hostname contain domain suffix

Answer (score 2):

You can get a host name like so, without Regex.

```
const getHostFromUrl = (url: string): string => {
  return new URL(url).hostname.replace("www.", "");
};

getHostFromUrl('https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ClkQA2Lb_iE') // youtube.com
```