# JavaScript regex to break an url into domain and path

Tags: javascript, regex

I need a regex to break a given url into two parts.

part1 --> the domain (including the protocol [http or https] if present).

part2 --> the remainder

Thus something like this:

example 1

`let url = "https://www.example.com/asdasd/123asdsd/sdasd?bar=1"`

regex returns

`domain = https://www.example.com`

`remaining path = /asdasd/123asdsd/sdasd?bar=1`

---

example 2

`let url = "www.example.com/asdasd/123asdsd/sdasd?bar=1"`

regex returns

`domain = www.example.com`

`remaining path = /asdasd/123asdsd/sdasd?bar=1`

---

example 3

`let url = "example.com/asdasd/123asdsd/sdasd?bar=1"`

regex returns

`domain = example.com`

`remaining path = /asdasd/123asdsd/sdasd?bar=1`

---

example 4

`let url = "http://example.com"`

regex returns

`domain = http://example.com`

`remaining path = null`

Comment: Do you have to use Regex, or could you use something like the JS URL interface? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL

Comment: Please refer to https://stackoverflow.com/a/569219

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the breakdown javascript version. Hope this helps understand

```
//removes protocol
let regEx = /^(?:www\.)?(.*?):\/\//gim;
let url = "https://www.example.com/asdasd/123asdsd/sdasd?bar=1"
let path = url.replace(regEx, "");
console.log("path = " + path);

//removes domain extracts route
let regEx2 = /^(.*?\/)/;
if (path.match(regEx2)) {
  let route = "/" + path.replace(regEx2, "");
  console.log("route", route);

  //extracts domain
  url = path.match(regEx2);
  let domainUrl = url[0].replace("/", "");
  console.log("domainUrl = ", domainUrl);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend using the [URL interface](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL) instead of a regex. Although it will not handle example 2 and 3, it can pull out all the bits you require.

From MDN:

> The URL interface is used to parse, construct, normalize, and encode URLs. It works by providing properties which allow you to easily read and modify the components of a URL. You normally create a new URL object by specifying the URL as a string when calling its constructor, or by providing a relative URL and a base URL. You can then easily read the parsed components of the URL or make changes to the URL.

Example for your requirements:

```js
let url = new URL("https://www.example.com/asdasd/123asdsd/sdasd?bar=1");

console.log("domain - " + url.origin);
console.log("remaining path - " + url.pathname + url.search);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`URL`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL).

```js
var url = new URL("https://www.example.com/asdasd/123asdsd/sdasd?bar=1");
var domain = `${url.protocol}//${url.host}`;
var path = `${url.pathname}?${url.searchParams.toString()}`;
console.log(`domain = ${domain}`)
console.log(`remaining path = ${path}`)
```

Someone beat me to the punch with URL so I'll post the regex as well.

```js
var url = "https://www.example.com/asdasd/123asdsd/sdasd?bar=1";
var matches = /(https?:\/\/.*?)([/$].*)/.exec(url);
var domain = matches[1];
var path = matches[2];
console.log(`domain = ${domain}`)
console.log(`remaining path = ${path}`)
```