# Is there a way to store all the while-loop values into the array?

Tags: php, while-loop, text-files

I am making a very comprehensive application, which I have been working on for a number of months. For my next step I am writing some code that will delete all the duplicate domains from my textfile.

What I previously did is use the (php) `array_unique();` function which would delete my exact duplicates from my txtfile. But I need to delete all the domains that are the same.

Old situation (this would delete url **1 or 2** because they are exact the same):

1. google.nl
2. google.nl
3. google.nl/hello

Desired situation (will delete **two of the three** urls because the domains are the same):

1. google.nl/hello
2. google.nl/yellow
3. google.nl

So I made a bit of code which shows every url that is in my txtfile onto the screen (nothing special). I do this by using a while-loop:

```
$file = fopen("file.txt","r");
while(! feof($file))
{
    echo fgets($file). "<br />";
}
```

So I used this tutorial to help myself: [how to get domain name from URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/569137/how-to-get-domain-name-from-url). This is the code that I used.

```
function parse_url_all($url){
    $url = substr($url,0,4)=='http'? $url: 'http://'.$url;
    $d = parse_url($url);
    $tmp = explode('.',$d['host']);
    $n = count($tmp);
    if ($n>=2){
        if ($n==4 || ($n==3 && strlen($tmp[($n-2)])<=3)){
            $d['domain'] = $tmp[($n-3)].".".$tmp[($n-2)].".".$tmp[($n-1)];
            $d['domainX'] = $tmp[($n-3)];
        } else {
            $d['domain'] = $tmp[($n-2)].".".$tmp[($n-1)];
            $d['domainX'] = $tmp[($n-2)];
        }
    }
    return $d;
}

$urls = array('website1','website2');
echo "<div style='overflow-x:auto;'>";
echo "<table style='text-align:left;'>";
echo "<tr><th>URL</th><th>Host</th><th>Domain</th><th>Domain X</th></tr>";
foreach ($urls as $url) {
    $info = parse_url_all($url);
    echo "<tr><td>" . $url . "</td><td>" . $info['host'] . "</td><td>" . $info['domain'] . "</td><td>" . $info['domainX'] . "</td></tr>";
}
echo "</table></div><br>";
```

How do I get the output of my while-loop (txtfile) into the array from this line:
`$urls = array('output from textfile');` It will probably be something simple, but I just couldn't figure it out.

Comment: you can get urls array as following: `$urls = array();
$handle = fopen("file.txt", "r");
if ($handle) {
    while (($line = fgets($handle)) !== false) {
        array_push($urls, $line);
    }

    fclose($handle);
} else {
    // error opening the file.
}
`

Comment: Thanks! Hero of the day!

Comment: Check it here for unique : https://repl.it/@arvindDhakad/DelayedLiquidInstructions-1

Comment: Thank you! Sadly Stackoverflow doesn't let me give you the 'solved' badge because it sees your answer as a comment.

Comment: @ArvindDhakad do you know how I save al these variables to a txtfile?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the snippet you can use to find unique urls and save it to file as csv:

```
<?php
function parse_url_all($url)
{
    $url = substr($url, 0, 4) == 'http' ? $url : 'http://' . $url;
    $d = parse_url($url);
    $tmp = explode('.', $d['host']);
    $n = count($tmp);
    if ($n >= 2)
    {
        if ($n == 4 || ($n == 3 && strlen($tmp[($n - 2) ]) <= 3))
        {
            $d['domain'] = $tmp[($n - 3) ] . "." . $tmp[($n - 2) ] . "." . $tmp[($n - 1) ];
            $d['domainX'] = $tmp[($n - 3) ];
        }
        else
        {
            $d['domain'] = $tmp[($n - 2) ] . "." . $tmp[($n - 1) ];
            $d['domainX'] = $tmp[($n - 2) ];
        }
    }
    return $d;
}


// read file and unique urls in array.
$urls = array();
$input_file = "urls.txt";
$handle = fopen($input_file, "r");
if ($handle)
{
    while (($line = fgets($handle)) !== false)
    {
        $parsed_url = parse_url_all(trim($line));
        // 'domain' is unique (i assume)
        $urls[$parsed_url["domain"]] = $parsed_url;
    }

    fclose($handle);
}
else
{
    // error opening the file.

}


// write output to csv
$headers = array("host", "domain", "domainX");
$output_file = "output.csv";

$fp = fopen($output_file, 'w');
fputcsv($fp, $headers);

foreach ( $urls as $url ) {
    $val = array($url["host"], $url["domain"], $url["domainX"]);
    fputcsv($fp, $val);
}

fclose($fp);
```

https://repl.it/@arvindDhakad/php-unique-urls-filter-DS

Comment: Change output.csv to output.txt

Comment: This is awesome! Thank you :)