# RegEX: How to get the domain-name from FQDN

Tags: regex, terraform

I'm pretty sure it should be simple enough to do but I cannot figure out. I have some FQDNs like:

1. api.mydiomain.org.local
2. app.stg.mydiomain.org.local
3. uses.anotherdomain.uk

and I like to extract *mydiomain.org.local*, *stg.mydiomain.org.local*, *anotherdomain.uk* etc. respectively using perl style regex. I tried `[\\W].+$`, which is giving me almost what I want but with the leading `.` (e.g. `.mydiomain.org.local`). And `[^\\W]+$` returning only the very last part (e.g. `local`). Any idea what am I missing here?

Just to mention that I'll be using this with terraform's [`regex()`](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/functions/regex) function, which is fully compatible with perl RegEx but if the pattern has no capture groups it returns a *string* but behaves differently for named and unnamed capture group(s), returning a *map{}* and *list()* instead.

Comment: See [zero-width positive lookbehind assertion](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlre#(?pattern)) in perlre, i.e. `(?<=\.)[\w.]+$`

Comment: try `^[^.]*\.\K.+$` https://regex101.com/r/4u43kl/1

Comment: Regex is not really necessary here. How about splitting the string by `.`, throw the first and join the rest?

Comment: You should update your question to note that you are using terraform so someone can suggest an appropriate terraform solution.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get domain name from URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/569137/how-to-get-domain-name-from-url)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hello try this regex  `^\w+\.(.*)`

Comment: Thanks @jean for your replay!
It's working but returning a _list_ (using it in Terraform) for me, in stead of string. I can do something like `regex("^\w+.(.+)", "api.mydiomain.org.local")[0]` to get the result as string but was wondering is there any way  a string can be returned without any further processing?

Comment: @MacUsers You can use `$1`. No "further processing" needed. Well, if you were actually using Perl as you stated. What you have there isn't Perl.