# implementing Public Suffix extraction using java

Tags: java, guava, domain-name, tld

i need to extract the top domain of an url and i got his `http://publicsuffix.org/index.html`

and the java implementation is in `http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com` and i could not find 
any example to extract domain name

```
say example..
example.google.com
returns google.com

and bing.bing.bing.com
returns bing.com
```

can any one tell me how can i implement using this library with an example....

Comment: So, you're looking to extract [TLD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Top-level_domain) (the `.com` part) and [SLD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Second-level_domain) (the `google` or `bing` part) from URLs?

Comment: If you just want the last two parts of the domain, couldn't you just `String.split('\\.')` to get the parts and return the last two?  Or do a `String.substring(indexOfPenultimatePeriod)` after (easily) working out the appropriate index?  What is the complexity here?

Comment: @Andrzej Doyle ya..you are right and that is an url list with 10k urls with different suffix like it has .com,.com.jp,.org,com.in,etc....

Comment: @ramuvan - good point, you should add those cases to the examples.  The only way to cope with this is to have a list of definitive TLDs, and match the end of your domain string against them.

Comment: @ramuvan: Guava does have a solution that makes this easy... see my answer.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

It looks to me like [InternetDomainName.topPrivateDomain()](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/net/InternetDomainName.html#topPrivateDomain%28%29) does *exactly* what you want. Guava maintains a list of public suffixes (based on Mozilla's list at publicsuffix.org) that it uses to determine what the public suffix part of the host is... the top private domain is the public suffix plus its first child.

Here's a quick example:

```
public class Test {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws URISyntaxException {
    ImmutableList<String> urls = ImmutableList.of(
        "http://example.google.com", "http://google.com", 
        "http://bing.bing.bing.com", "http://www.amazon.co.jp/");
    for (String url : urls) {
      System.out.println(url + " -> " + getTopPrivateDomain(url));
    }
  }

  private static String getTopPrivateDomain(String url) throws URISyntaxException {
    String host = new URI(url).getHost();
    InternetDomainName domainName = InternetDomainName.from(host);
    return domainName.topPrivateDomain().name();
  }
}
```

Running this code prints:

```
http://example.google.com -> google.com
http://google.com -> google.com
http://bing.bing.bing.com -> bing.com
http://www.amazon.co.jp/ -> amazon.co.jp
```

Comment: TLD and Public Suffix are not the same. For example `http://myblog.blogspot.com -> myblog.blogspot.com`. Read [this](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/InternetDomainNameExplained) for further details

Comment: Do you know why `s3.amazonaws.com` returns a null?

Comment: @Liquid: `s3.amazonaws.com` is itself a public suffix: https://publicsuffix.org/list/effective_tld_names.dat

Comment: Sorry, I works well... I implement it in a wrong way.

Comment: `[javac] symbol  : method name()
    [javac] location: class com.google.common.net.InternetDomainName
    [javac]                             this.domain = domainName.topPrivateDomain().name();
    [javac]                                                                        ^
    [javac] Note: Some input files use unchecked or unsafe operations.
    [javac] Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
    [javac] 1 error
` What does this error mean? why `.name()` method??

Answer (score 2):

I recently implemented a [Public Suffix List API](https://github.com/whois-server-list/public-suffix-list):

```
PublicSuffixList suffixList = new PublicSuffixListFactory().build();

assertEquals(
    "google.com", suffixList.getRegistrableDomain("example.google.com"));

assertEquals(
    "bing.com", suffixList.getRegistrableDomain("bing.bing.bing.com"));

assertEquals(
    "amazon.co.jp", suffixList.getRegistrableDomain("www.amazon.co.jp"));
```

Comment: Do you know why `s3.amazonaws.com` returns a null?

Comment: The [PSL](https://publicsuffix.org/) considers `s3.amazonaws.com` as an public suffix.

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: Sorry I've been a little too fast. I didn't think of co.jp. co.uk, and so on. You will need to get a list of possible TLDs from somewhere. You could also take a look at http://commons.apache.org/validator/ to validate a TLD.

I think something like this should work: But maybe there exists some Java-Standard Function.

```
String url = "http://www.foobar.com/someFolder/index.html";
if (url.contains("://")) {
  url = url.split("://")[1];
}

if (url.contains("/")) {
  url = url.split("/")[0];
}

// You need to get your TLDs from somewhere...
List<String> magicListofTLD = getTLDsFromSomewhere();

int positionOfTLD = -1;
String usedTLD = null;
for (String tld : magicListofTLD) {
  positionOfTLD = url.indexOf(tld);
  if (positionOfTLD > 0) {
    usedTLD = tld;
    break;
  }
}

if (positionOfTLD > 0) {
  url = url.substring(0, positionOfTLD);
} else {
  return;
}
String[] strings = url.split("\\.");

String foo = strings[strings.length - 1] + "." + usedTLD;
System.out.println(foo);
```

Comment: yeah, sorry, didn't think of co.jp, co.uk and so on. I guess you have to get a list of possible TLDs and try to match them with the String.

Comment: Guava has built in functionality for doing this, including an internal TLD list that will be updated with new releases as the TLD list changes. On top of that, Java has built in functionality for parsing and getting the host part of a URL... I don't think parsing it out manually with `split` is a good idea.

Comment: @ColinD: Nice library. Didn't know of it.